# Is there a nuance of difference between "I lied" and "I was lying"?

Tags: difference, past-simple, past-continuous

Can you please tell me if there is a nuance of difference between *I lied* and *I was lying*? For example:

> When I said that I was going to go home, **I lied**.
>
> When I said that I was going to go home, **I was lying**.

I'm very well of the difference between the past simple and the past continuous, but I can't see any difference in meaning between the two in that sentence. I've heard people use both. I'd like to know if there are contexts where you would use one rather than the other.

Comment: I can tell you that "I was lying" feels more natural to me, but both sound good and I can't detect any difference in meaning in this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning.

There **may** be a very slight difference in tone.

> I lied when I said that

indicates that two things happened in the past concurrently, but duration is ignored.

> I was lying when I said that

also indicates that two things happened in the past concurrently, but the fact the lying had duration is acknowledged. In some contexts, that acknowledgement may be significant.

Because no action is truly instantaneous, the two statements have no difference in fundamental meaning and **may or may not** be be trying to differentiate almost subliminally between a duration so short as to represent an instant and a duration that is meaningfully different from an instant. In the huge majority of cases, no such subtlety is intended or even recognized.

Answer (score 0):

The simple past and the past continuous are used together when something happened in the middle of something else.

We use the past continuous (I was lying) to describe the background and the simple past (I lied) for the actions (past continuous- background or temporary event, simple past- finished event)

Two events happened in the past. We can use the simple past (I lied) to emphasise the main event and the past continuous (I was lying) for the background event.

**I lied**- main event (focus on the event)

**I was lying**- the less important event

Two events happened simultaneously. When I said... **I lied.**
When I said...**I was lying**.

[I was walking home when I met Farukh.

I was walking home- background event, I met Farukh- main event]